# SSD and HDD: Failure probabilities

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

I'm stuck in a dilemma.

1. To buy an external HDD for back up and use existing HDD for my desktop or
2. Buy SSD and use it as a primary while using the existing HDD(connected to the PC) as a backup for data?

I'm using an AMD fx processor with 6 cores and existing HDD is 500Gb.
my work involves running programs with lots of computations per second.

I'm looking for a solution which is more reliable in keeping my backup data safe.

Comment: It was mentioned in another comment to rotate through multiple external drives for backup. Do not use a drive that is installed inside the PC for backups. That drive would be vulnerable to all kinds of errors, power surges, viruses, and user mistakes as it is constantly connected to the PC. A drive that is not connected to the PC is going to be much more reliable for keeping your data backed up. And obviously a drive could just randomly fail, use multiple drives if it is absolutely critical to keep the backup safe. Keep an extra drive in a 2nd location if you are worried about fire or theft.

Comment: What's your budget? You want to backup how much data (10GB, 100GB, 1TB)? What you like to prevent data loss, because of HW failure, weather, fire, burglary, ...? You want do manual backup or automatic one? Do you want backup whole system or just particular data (e.g. photos, documents, ...)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buy an SSD because of the fast response times and they are not that more expensive than a hard drive. You should probably get a SATA ssd, like a crucial mx 500 because old processors like amd fx don't have nvme support. If yours does have nvme support, try a kingston a2000. But the best way to keep your backup safe is multiple ssd's in raid1, but thats pretty expensive.

Comment: I would argue that the best method to keep your backups safe is several external hard drives where you make a complete backup on one of them over night and swap through all drives over the weeks. Additionally it is advisable to have at least one of them stored at a different location for backup safety. If the data is sensitive (which it most likely is), I think the backups should be encrypted, but this can prove problematic in some scenarios where recovery is necessary.

Comment: True, but you can also take the hard drive out of the computer and buy a cheap usb to sata cable and use it as an external hdd

Comment: **RAID 1 is absolutely not a backup solution! At all!**
If you delete a file on a RAID 1, where are you going to look for the file when you want it back? RAID 1 provides hardware failure tolerance, **it does not protect your data from getting destroyed or corrupted by software** issues.

Comment: But we are not raiding the origional drive, we are raiding the backup drive, so the backup is safer

Comment: I still think you misunderstand the use-case for RAID 1. It does not protect the content of the disk from software modification. If a virus or mistake by the user were to delete that backup, the backup is gone for good. If you want your backup to be "safe", keep multiple **offline** copies of it. Anything connected to the PC is at risk of being deleted at any moment, for whatever reason.

Comment: True, but this question was about hardware failure, not software falure

Comment: And because RAID1 protects against hardware failures, that is an ok option

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I bought a crucial SSD and am using the one in my PC as a backup drive. It perfectly serves the purpose and fits in my budget as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to truly protect against drive failure your should invest in a RAID 6, unfortunately it needs a minimum of 4 drives and a controller card so it going to get expensive.

If you need to protect against data corruption, then you need a backup system to another drive and/or cloud backup.

Comment: I would not reccomend cloud backups though, except if you encrypt it before you upload it.